# What is a good way to assign a model object to a symbol after saving it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I return the object after a model save like:

```
      Message.new(:receiver => receiver, :sender => self, 
      :subject => subject,
      :body => body).save
```

I understand I could probably do a

```
      Message.last
```

But will there be any implications during a high traffic time period where the database is constantly being accessed? I'm afraid that Message.last will return another record.

Comment: I think you're missing some basic concepts.  You may wish to review Ruby or Ruby on Rails again.  Also, you can't use 'self' as it is a reserved word in ruby.

Answer (score 1):

If you're directly creating the object, you can use the create method, which creates and returns it.

```
message = Message.create(...)
```

It does the same then what's suggested by DR. But in only one code line :)